# how to echo the result of a javascript id result into the value of an html form

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
function onclickbutton(value) {
    document.getElementByid("clicked").innerHTML = value;
}
</script>
```

let say this code is used to print the result of a javascript function

```
  <button class="btn btn-primary"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="onclickbutton(<?php echo($level->getPotentialEarning()); ?> )">
Recycle
```

```
<p id="clicked"></p>


<input type="text"  name="amount" value=""  readonly>
```

because all my idea to make it work out as the same value is not working out

Comment: Can you add the javascript you're using?

Comment: Hi @phemiery7, edit with your javascript and make easy to read and help you

Comment: @Avitus i have update the code

Comment: @SayuriMizuguchi i have include the javascript

Comment: What does your rendered HTML look like? Is the PHP giving the right values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Gets id of <p> 
var test = document.getElementById('test').id;
// Assign test to the input value
$("#test2").val(test);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="test"></p>
<input id="test2">
```

Comment: You really should mention that this uses jQuery.